# calculating a css easing function from an svg path

Tags: css, svg, css-transitions, css-animations, cubic-bezier

I have a circle that follows an svg path using the css `offset-path` declaration:

```
circle {
  offset-path: path('M-0.4-3.3l-30,50c0,0,27,79,79,79c0,0-72-32-79-170c0,0-145,86-254-40');
}'
```

Then I have an animation with a set of keyframes for how far along that animation should be at each phase of the animation:

```
@keyframes circlePath {
    0% {
        offset-distance: 0%;
    }

    10% {
        offset-distance: 8.8%
    }

    56% {
        offset-distance: 25.7%
    }

    84% {
        offset-distance: 54.2%
    }

    100% {
        offset-distance: 100%;
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

and if I were to graph out the easing curve I want at each step of the way, it would look like the second image below, and have the following svg path coords:

```
<path class="st0" d="M284.4,81.3l-30,50c0,0,27,79,79,79c0,0-72-32-79-170c0,0-145,86-254-40"/>
```

Is there a way to create a css easing function from that path? Or in other words, is there a way to create a multi-stage bezier easing function?

Motion Path:
[image: motion path]

Easing at each step of the path's progress:

[image: easing at each step of the path's progress]

Comment: You don't need to. The easing function can be applied on a keyframe basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define easing functions on a per-keyframe basis by setting `animation-timing-function`. This is a simplified version of your requirements, just to exemplify:

```
@keyframes circlePath {
    0% {
        offset-distance: 0%;
        animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    }

    10% {
        offset-distance: 8.8%
        animation-timing-function: linear;
    }

    56% {
        offset-distance: 25.7%
        animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    }

    84% {
        offset-distance: 54.2%
        animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    }

    100% {
        offset-distance: 100%;
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

You will probably need to define [cubic bezier functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/single-transition-timing-function) to get the precise result you wanted.

Comment: Wow - I had no idea you could do separate timing functions! That's exactly what I need. Didn't occur to me to try that. Thanks!

Comment: to be honest, I also had to look it up :)